# Are session variables shared across threads?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multithreading, session

I am working on a VB.Net project, and I want a fast and dirty way of having a second thread preform some function, then store some variable outcome to the session. Then I want to access that variable from the first thread (in the same session of course).

Here is an example of the code...

Button#1

```
Sub button_Click1(byVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Event Args)

textfield1.Visible = False
lable2.Visible = True
textfield2.Visible = True
button_Click2.Visible = True

Dim thread2 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf foothread)
thread2.Start(textfield1.Text.ToString)

End Sub
```

Button#2

```
Sub button_Click2(byVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Event Args)
If(textfield2.Text = "is cool" And System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("myBool") = true) Then
 lable2 = "You're right!"
 else
 lable2 = "???"
 end If
```

Thread #2

```
Public Sub thread2(ByVal str1 As String)

If(srt1 = "Stack/Flow") Then
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("myBool") = true 
Else
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("myBool") = false
End If

End Sub
```

Obviously this is not a real production example, I am running a lengthy query in the thread which will return my session variable (lengthy due to network traffic to that box)

Is this possible? Is there a better way? Will this even work? 
New to multithreaded applications.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that doesn't work. The second thread doesn't have a HTTP context, only threads that run to handle requests have a HTTP context.

Youcan make a class for the method to run in the second thread, and add any input and output data as members in the class:

```
Public Class Thread2Class

  Public Str1 As String    
  Public MyBool As Boolean

  Public Sub Run()

    If Str1 = "Stack/Flow" Then
      MyBool = True 
    Else
      MyBool = False
    End If

  End Sub

End Class
```

Create an instance of the class, set the input data, and start the thread:

```
Dim thread2 As New Thread2Class
thread2.Str1 = Lable1.Text.ToString
Dim thread2 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf thread2.Run)
thread2.Start()
```

Keep the reference to the class, so that you can read the result from the member when the thread has finished:

```
Dim result As Boolean = thread2.MyBool
```

Comment: If I used a dirty, filthy *shudders at the thought*  **global variable** would the global variable be accessible from both threads?

Comment: @Christopher: It would be accessible from all threads, but all users would share the same variable. You wouldn't know which user put the result in the variable.